# Using getColumnDisplaySize() for neatness?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, metadata, resultset

I was wondering whether you could use `getColumnDisplaySize()` to produce a neater table with the results in the correct columns and how could I do this?

This is my code at the moment.

```
stmt = con.createStatement();  
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderID");

if (res.next()) {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        columnHeading = columnHeading + "\t" + rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    }
    System.out.println(columnHeading);

    do {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {                            
            System.out.print("\t" + res.getString(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    } while(res.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not try that.

The `getcolumnDisplaySize()` method gives you the column width as specified by the (SQL) column type.  This bears little relation to the width of the largest value in the table at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually set the size of a table column the read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Columns Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width).

If you want to automatically calculate the size of the columns then you can try the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/).